# Custom template for specific post type archive

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For the custom post type "Product" in Woocommerce, I wish to create a custom archive page for the taxonomy "Seating".

According to the Wordpress codex the order should be "archive" then "post type" then "taxonomy"

I have therefore tried the following file names:

archive-product-seating.php

category-product-seating.php

archive-product-category-seating.php

category-product-category-seating.php

Is it possible to create a specific template for a specific taxonomy of a post type? if so, how is this named?

I also understand that this could be achieved by using conditional logic... I'm trying to not do this though.

Comment: For WooCommerce `'product'` post type there is 2 custom taxonomies, product categories (`'product_cat'`) and Product tags (`'product_tag'`). Also each product `attribute` is a custom taxonomy (`pa_`+ the attribute name). So may be "Seating" is not a taxonomy but a **"product category" term** (which taxonomy is `'product_cat'` for a product category or subcategory)… So it's going to use [WooCommerce template](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) `archive-product.php` (with other woocommerce sub templates like `content-product_cat.php` and `taxonomy-product_cat.php`)…

Answer (score 0):

According to this page https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ (picture is very useful) filename should be taxonomy-product-seating.php